# AWS Lambdas Functions VS EC2 for Image Sharing App

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, architecture, serverless

I am still getting a grip on AWS Technologies so bear with me.

Project Background

I am currently developing a somewhat complex web app (with a few classmates) that will take user-uploaded images (much like Pinterest) and display them in a grid for users (most likely with a GET request). I am just still researching whether I should use a lambda function or a dedicated EC2 instance (because of lambda's limitations) for continual scrolling images / data delivery to the user.

**My question is**: where should I store the code for a service making this type of continual GET requests based on user scroll?

I am confused due to AWS Lambdas' memory limitations, payload size, and how long each request can run. I am also worried that it might cost me more in the long term to use lambdas for such continual `GET` requests. Am I better off just using an EC2 Instance and provision it myself? Or can AWS lambdas handle such a process with ease? I have been researching and haven't found much.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as a perfect scenario for a serverless solution. I would architect this as follows:

- S3 - To store images publicly accessible.
- DynamoDB - To store image urls based on the users (may be)
- API Gateway - To fetch data when user scrolls.
- Lambda - API Gateway talks to this Lambda to get the image urls.

Whenever user scrolls, a api request goes through API gateway to Lambda, and it will query in Dynamodb and sends back the urls of the images (not the images itself). As far as I can see, this will not even reach lamda's memory and time limitation and mainly you only pay for what you use and not for the idle time when user doesn't use the application (which is the case for EC2 approach)

Comment: Thank you very much! My classmates and I will look into this approach!

Answer (score 0):

Can the images in the bucket be made available to the public?  At first glance, I would just use the Lambda function to build a list of images in that bucket and then configure your web app to download those images when the app/browser needed them.

You could also do all of this with the AWS SDK if you need to figure out authentication, anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I will definitely look into this!